# Javascript function not working, but it's identical to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to add a Sortable functions to several lists.

I have this function:

```
       launchSortable : function launchSortable() {
            Sortable.create(byId('col0'), this.sortableParams);
            Sortable.create(byId('col1'), this.sortableParams);
            Sortable.create(byId('col2'), this.sortableParams);
        }
```

In my html I have several lists with class `editableList` and id col1, col2, col3 etc...

I try to refactor the function in this way:

```
        launchSortableLoop : function launchSortable() {
            $editableList.each(function(index, value) {
                var id = ('col' + index);
                Sortable.create(byId(id), this.sortableParams);
            });
        },
```

It doesn't work...

Why?

Comment: Could it be that your index is off? Have you tried to test the second or third list to see if it works? The first portion of the code you start with col0.....but then you mention having the id as col1....(not col0).

Comment: is `this.sortableParams` what you expect? i think each() might have it's own context by default...

Comment: Stepping through the code with the debugger would help you find the problem.  Per above comments, some variable is probably not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `this.sortableParams` is properly in scope?  What happens if you try this modification?

```
launchSortableLoop : function launchSortable() {
    var that = this;
    $editableList.each(function(index, value) {
        var id = ('col' + index);
        Sortable.create(byId(id), that.sortableParams);
    });
},
```